# mv is not a function while using express-fileUpload

Tags: express, file-upload

I am trying to upload array of images into a folder with express-fileUpload, and it returns that mv is not a function. I tried finding the solution on the internet, but there is no working one. Whatvever I change I get the same error, there may be something behind the hood. Also I am working with images that are saved in localStorage, so they are data images.

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());

...

  const productsJson = {
    properties: req.body.products,
  };

  productsJson.properties.forEach((e) => {
    e.meshImgs.forEach((el, index) => {
      console.log(el) // data:image/png;base64,iVB...
      el.mv(__dirname + '../public/UserFolder/' + index);
    });
  });
```

Comment: The upload file object is attached on `req.files` property, not `req.body`

Comment: I am using local storage to get images and put them in react redux. Should I separate images from the data object and take it by req.files (will it work like that)?